# multiple setTimeouts cancel each other out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue when I call multiple `setTimeout`s, It seems they cancel each other out when fired rapidly one after the other.

Given this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/72M6L/ .

which shows this very simple object:

```
fadepopup = function (msg) 
{
    $elm = $('<div class="fadepopup"></div>');
    $elm.html('msg');
    $('body').append($elm);

    setTimeout(function () 
    {
        $elm.fadeOut(500, function () 
        {
            $(this).remove()
        });
    }, 1500);
}
```

If you push the button once(in the fiddle), everything is great.
If you push the button multiple time quickly, the div does not get removed.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can set the timeout to a variable and cancel it before the new one runs

Comment: Can I ask you to explain a bit more the mechanics behind it? As i'm calling a new instance of `fadepopup` I don't see any relation and correlation between the different setTimeouts

Comment: Your use of implicit global variables is certainly part of the issue. Every time there's a click, the `$elm` is overwritten with a new element, so the `setTimeout` callbacks are going to refer to the new one, not the original which it was going to fade.

Comment: ...the solution ultimately depends on what you're trying to do. Do you actually want multiple elements positioned atop each other, or should the existence of one prevent new ones from being created?

Comment: Grumble Grumble, `$elm global var`, Thanks ! ;) Removing the old popups if they exist is easy enough, I can't believe I missed that global :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the global variable `$elm`. When you click the button before the timeout has executed the variable has been overwritten, and the method (`$elm.fadeOut`) is no longer bound to that element (because the variable refers to the newest element that was created instead).

My suggestion is to use `var` within the function to make it local:

`var $elm = $('<div class="fadepopup"></div>');`

See [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72M6L/1/)

Comment: Good illustration why it's so important never to forget `var`.

Comment: Duh! I feel stupid :)

There's a lesson for you kids, NEVER forget a `var` :)